# Segmentation fault on pthread_join()

Tags: segmentation-fault

Can't understand case of segfault.

```
int main()
{
     int val;
     pthread_t thread;
 ...........................
     pthread_join(thread,(void **) &val);  
     printf("Val=%d",val);   
 //and here sometimes come segmentation 
 //fault and other times i get correct val value

 ...........................
}

void *Do(void *)
{
    int retval=4;
...............
    pthread_exit((void *) retval);
}
```

If i'm correct, pthread_exit() stores addres (which value is 4) into variable which is pointed by (&val) pointer, which means that val=4 after pthread_join(). 
But the point that if i launch program many times i got both correct val value (that is 4) and segmentation faults on different launches. (btw the same result when did in correct way with pointers and dynamic allocation in Do function).

Help me, please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You took out too much.  While you're adding more, fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of, is the fact that you are returning the address of local variable of function *Do. Local variables are stored in the stack frame alocated for the function.You are returning a pointer to a location that is not valid after the thread has terminated.

See :

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html

where is says:

> The value pointed to by retval should not be located on the calling
>   thread's stack, since the contents of that stack are undefined after
>   the thread terminates.

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_exit((void *) retval);
```

This takes an integer (with an undetermined size) and casts it to a pointer with a potentially different size. I would say that most of the time this is fine as sizeof(void *) >= sizeof(int).

```
pthread_join(thread,(void **) &val);
```

This call is really only valid if sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *). If you are on a 64 bit system then &val points to 4 bytes of space but you are telling the compiler it points to 8. If this address is in the right place (at the end of your allocated virtual address space) then it will segfault in pthread_join trying to write the void pointer.

What you should do is:

```
void *retval;
pthread_join(thread, (void **), &retval);
val = (int)retval;
```

The cast from a pointer to the int will truncate any of the more significant bits. Also if it was a 64 bit big endian system you would never get the correct val because the 4 bytes actually storing the data are the second 4 bytes.

Contrary to the other answer it is perfectly fine to pass integer return values back by casting to void * and then back to the desired integer type. You just wouldn't want to pass actual pointers to data on the stack that you intend to dereference as you would be invoking undefined behavior. At the end of the day a pointer is nothing more than an unsigned integer whose value normally points to some place in memory.